# Вызвать внутреннюю функцию javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

Как вызвать внутреннюю функцию javascript
вот функция

```
function validate(params, callback) {
     // some code....
     this.results = function () {
           alert('work!');
      } 

      callback();
}

var res = function () {
      validate.results(); // здесь появляется ошибка
}

 validate (params, res);
```

пробую вызвать внутреннюю функцию через каллбек но получаю ошибку `validate.results is not a function`

Comment: это не внутренняя функция а пользовательская

Comment: я не совсем пойму, что именно вы хотите получить? с одной стороны - передаете callback, с другой не вызываете его. как вы хотите использовать ваш код?

Comment: @Grundy поправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одно из решений, просто передавать функцию *results* в callback

```
function validate(params, callback) {
     // some code....
     function results() {
           alert('work!');
      } 

      callback(results);
}

var res = function (validateResults) {
      validateResults(); // все ОК
}

validate (params, res);
```

Еще одно вместо *this* использовать имя функции, так как значение *this* зависит от того, как была вызвана функция.

```
function validate(params, callback) {
     // some code....
     validate.results = function () {
           alert('work!');
      } 

      callback();
}

var res = function () {
      validate.results(); // здесь появляется ошибка
}
validate (params, res);
```

Еще решение - использовать оператор *new*

```
function validate(params, callback) {
     // some code....
     this.results = function () {
           alert('work!');
      } 

      callback(this);
}

var res = function (validate) {
      validate.results(); // здесь появляется ошибка
}
new validate (params, res);
```

Еще решение - использовать оператор *new*, версия 2

```
function validate(params, callback) {
     // some code....
     this.results = function () {
           alert('work!');
      } 

      callback();
}

var res = function () {
      validateObj.results(); // здесь появляется ошибка
}
var validateObj = new validate (params, res);
```

Comment: Мне важно что-бы она не передавалась туда а была постоянно там и я мог ее через калбеки вызывать

Comment: @modelfak, мне кажется, вы себе немного не правильно представляете, как это работает, в любом случае обновил ответ и добавил еще несколько возможных решений

Comment: @modelfak, возможность вызывать через колбэки прекрасно реализуется если передавать параметр, либо вы хотите не правильно использовать колбэки, можете добавить в вопрос, несколько вариантов как вы хотите использовать ваш код, и почему _важно что-бы она не передавалась туда а была постоянно там_?